# How to replace a number of words in a dataframe column with a character and the capture group

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe with a text column. The text has several words in it that delimit the text. I would like to replace the words with themselves but also with a "~" just in front of them

The text looks like

```
"Where did you go: I went to the shops. Why? I wanted to buy food how: By train When was this: A while ago"
```

I want to create the text:

```
"~Where did you go: I went to the shops. ~Why? I wanted to buy food ~How: By train. ~When was this: A while ago"
```

So basically: to find and replace multiple words as above in a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.replace` should have worked for you.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'foo': [
        '"Where did you go: I went to the shops. Why? I wanted to buy food how: By train When was this: A while ago"',
        '"Where did you go: I went to the shops. Why? I wanted to buy food how: By train When was this: A while ago"',
        '"Where did you go: I went to the shops. Why? I wanted to buy food how: By train When was this: A while ago"'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df['foo'] = df['foo'].str.replace(r'\b((?:When)|(?:Where)|(?:How)|(?:Why))\b',
                                  r'~\1',
                                  case=False,
                                  regex=True)

for r in df.itertuples():
    print(r.foo)
```